# Size retina text logo photoshop

Tags: wordpress, web, png, photoshop, retina

My wordpress theme has a feature to upload retina logo's. I want to use a text logo. The description says I should upload a double sized logo. I don't understand if I have to create a new png file with all dimensions x 2, or if I have to create a new logo with my current text size (points or pixels) x 2?

Could anyone you help me?

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language.  Please don't use it's tag for questions relating to graphical logos.

Comment: sorry, didn't realize :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimensions of your logo need to be doubled (in pixels) to keep the resolution high, so indeed, you need to go back to Photoshop create even 3 or 4 times the size of your current logo - design it with the canvas and resave it as PNG or whichever format you need. If you need some more help regarding the logo - am here to help.

PS. If your logo is text based do it also on Photoshop, retina will make it scalable anyways.